# Create Azure servicebus subscription from another pipeline then the one that creates the servicebus

Tags: azure, subscription, servicebus

Within Azure DevOps I have two pipelines. Pipeline A creates a servicebus with topics. Pipeline B wants to create a subscription on one of the topics from the servicebus.
So for one strange reason I can't get it working to create the subscription from pipeline B. It constantly complains about not finding the servicebus resource. I've done some searching and the only solutions that I could find where creating servicebus topics and subscriptions in once. But in my opinion this is not correct, because why should the creator of the servicebus also be involved in creating the subscriptions???

So my question: is it possible to create a subscription from another pipeline (and thus another resourcegroup) and if so, how would I do this.

Thanks in advance,

Herman

Comment: I think you can, but you would need to run a template containing only the topic against the resource group containing the SB namespace. I don't think the topic subscriptions can be in a different RG.

Comment: Thanks @juunas. I didn't meant to create the subscription in a different resourcegroup, but the pipeline originally deploys resources in another group and I want to add the subscription deployment to it (but offcourcse in the same group as the servicebus). Do you have an example?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an example :\ But in essence you are creating a child resource that you'll have to specify as a top-level resource instead of a nested resource (maybe nested works with Bicep's "existing resource" support but not sure). Also be sure to use Incremental deployment mode :)

Comment: Alternatively you could use some kind of CLI commands to create the subscription.